# How to apply action the_post to the post that is only being mainly displayed

Tags: actions

I'm trying to write an action that will modify some WooCommerce product on its display.

This is my simple code

```
function do_some_modifications($post)
{
    if (is_singular('product')) {
        // do some action
    }
    return $post;
}
add_action('the_post', 'do_some_modifications');
```

But the page contains two related products and "the_post" is called for them as well. How can I avoid running that code for additional products displayed on the main product page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Here we go!

I needed this to be implemented within only one plugin, not inside the template.

So I found out how to get the ID of current post outside the loop.
The great function [get_queried_object()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) and [get_queried_object_id()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object_id) will seal the deal!

It might not seem the quickiest way (it queries the database) but in my case it is a perfect solution since I'm running this code not for every page and not every time it's loaded.

And the final code is

```
function do_some_modifications($post)
{
    if (is_singular('product') and get_queried_object_id() == $post->ID) {
        // do some action
    }
    return $post;
}
add_action('the_post', 'do_some_modifications');
```

Comment: Note: This works for single posts only. But on archive pages/blog-home/etc the function `get_queried_object_id()` returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
    if (is_singular('product')){
      //  do some action
    }
```

with

```
    if (is_singular('product') && is_main_query()){
      //  do some action
    }
```

Comment: [`is_main_query()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_main_query/) function doesn't do what you think it does. It's pointless to use in this way.

Comment: Yes. is_main_query() will hit true both times.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement it would be to add the callback before main loop in template and remove after. Not too tidy from template perspective however.

Working purely with hooks you might want to check it if the post is present in `$wp_query->posts`, however that would misfire on duplicates.

In the past I remember doing this by adding custom marker property to the post object, but that was before `WP_Post` class was introduced and I am not sure it's viable technique anymore.

Comment: Well. I'm yet building the logic of my site. No theme applied yet. Can I implement this without touching template? Preferably within single plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, for this Stack question asked, the magic built in `in_the_loop()` does the job for me:

```
function do_some_modifications($post){
    if(is_singular('product') && in_the_loop()) {
        // do some action
    }
}
add_action('the_post', 'do_some_modifications');
```

You can skip `return $post` as this action is passing `$post` by reference.

I think the `do_action('the_post')` *is* the way to go here, not fibbling around inserting template actions, specially not woocommerce, they have templates for everything and changing them all the time.

I had a similar situation when my official plugin should do stuff before a shared template is called. Here **I dont know in advanced what template the Theme would use**, so I needed exactly as in this case, **target the archive product listing**, but **not related product listings below** or other widgets that *may* use the *same template*.

In case some other resourcing about this, to target sidebars only, set the conditional the opposite way `!in_the_loop()` and you may have to examine the `$post` before you do your stuff

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most reliable way I can think of, is using the second parameter of the [`the_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/) action:

```
function do_some_modifications( $post, $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        // do some action
    }
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'do_some_modifications', 10, 2 );
```

Some notes:

1. The **second parameter** of the filter callback provides the actual [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) object that is currently processed.
2. Also, [`the_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/) is an action and therefore does **not need a return value**. Instead of returning the $post value, you can directly modify the $post variable (it is a reference to the actual object that WordPress uses)
3. When you use the function [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) it will always check the main WP_Query object. If you want to check the query that's currently processed by [`the_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/) then you need to use [**`$query->is_singular()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_singular/).